# VBA index in function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm really new to VBA (10 hours) coming from a bit of a Python background. Is there a VBA equivilant to Python when it comes to indexing part of a returned function? This is what I mean:
If I have VBA code that looks like this:

```
Split(Worksheets("range").Range("K2").Offset(i, 0), "-", "-1")
```

And I only want the third part of the split, how would I get just that to output?

I imagine this is a really simple question but I can't seem to think it through. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Split(Worksheets("range").Range("K2").Offset(i, 0), "-", "-1")(2)` would work with the default `Option Base 0` setting, but as others have noted this might raise an error if there's no theird element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this function is setting the value of a variant/array variable, e.g.,:

```
Dim myArray as Variant
myArray = Split(Worksheets("range").Range("K2").Offset(i, 0), "-", "-1")
```

Then you should be able to refer to the 3rd item in the array like:

```
Debug.Print myArray(2) 'Option Base 0 -- Default'
```

Or, if you have `Option Base 1` then:

```
Debug.Print myArray(3)
```

Those examples use a constant expression (2 or 3) to index the array item. You could also use the match function to return a dynamic value, e.g., let's say you are looking for the value of "Steve" in this array:

```
Dim aItem as Long
aItem = Application.Match("Steve", myArray, False)
```

This returns a long/integer which you could then reference like:

```
Debug.Print myArray(aItem)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Dim splitArr() as String, Counter as Long
Dim textString as String
textString = Worksheets("range").Range("K2").Offset(i, 0).Value2


splitArr = split(textString,"-",-1)
For cntr = LBound(splitArr) To UBound(splitArr)
    'here you can process splitArr(cntr)
Next cntr

' Just accessing the third element can be done by accessing splitArr(LBound(splitArr)+2)
```

Note that depending on your settings Arrays in VBA an start either from 0 or from 1, the above code works in either case. Also note that you probably would need to catch of errors / would end up with an unitialized array if the string is empty.